# Angular ng-repeat animate once

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I am using `ngAnimate` to animate entries in an `ng-repeat`. When loading the data all elements are animated as I have defined in my css:

```
.chat-message.notice.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: rubberBand 1s;
    -moz-animation: rubberBand 1s;
    -ms-animation: rubberBand 1s;
    animation: rubberBand 1s;
}
```

This works when a notice is appended with the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="media chat-message pointer fade-animate"
        ng-repeat-start="message in guestbook.messages track by $index"
        ng-if="!message.bot">
        <!-- more html -->
    </li>
    <li class="chat-message notice" ng-repeat-end ng-if="message.bot">
        <div>
            <p class="text-center">
                {{ message.message }}
                <small>({{ message.date | amTimeAgo }})</small>
                <span class="close pull-right" ng-click="guestbook.remove(message)">&times;</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, when a new message is appended (at the top), every element is again animated. Is there a way that elements animate only once? That when a new message is appended to the array, only that element will animate?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t6x3a1zj/5/)

**EDIT**

After a few clicks on a 'new message', I can see not all notices are animated. Maybe it has something to do with the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even above answer fixed the problem, my solution might be helpful in other scenarios. The fix is pretty straightforward.

Use Angular varible **$first** and just add CSS class for the first element using ng-class directive in your HTML. In this example, class "first" will be added only to first element in ng-repeat:

```
ng-class="{'first': $first===true}"
```

and then apply animation rules to element with "first" CSS class

```
.chat-message.notice.first.ng-enter {
    color:red !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    animation: rubberBand 1s;
}
```

**Updated JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/t6x3a1zj/7/

Comment: This sounds like a nice solution, but still there is weird behaviour: when multiple notices are appended after eachother, not all are animated

Comment: I would need to recreate this bug, before I could help you. Do you refer to my example - http://jsfiddle.net/t6x3a1zj/7/ ?

Comment: Yeah you can see it in your example, when there are 2 bot messages after eachother, only the first one is animated: http://jsfiddle.net/t6x3a1zj/10/

Comment: I think i figured it out. The problem is caused by "track by $index". When removed, work like a charm. Check my update jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/t6x3a1zj/11/

Comment: You are correct! That is pretty weird. I'm going to file an issue with angular, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If understood correctly just change this:

```
$scope.messages.unshift(message);
```

to this:

```
$scope.messages.push(message);
```

Comment: Wow I thought you did not understand me, but is seems it fixes the issue! Your answer opened my eyes that (off course!) every element is animated because they gain a new position in the array, hence they 'enter'. Thank you :)

Comment: It feels always nice to help :) If you would like me to edit my answer to what you're expecting please to do ask me to do it.

Comment: The only issue here is how can I then display the `ng-repeat` in reversed order?

Comment: `ng-repeat-start="message in messages | orderBy:date:true"` and you're ready.

Comment: It looks like the `orderBy:'date':true` doesn't work in combination with an `ng-repeat-start`

Comment: Not when using the `push` instead of the `unshift`

Comment: I'm sorry maybe you have to post a different question. Fo4 me it seems to work. I'll try again kater for a diff solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78788/discussion-between-devqon-and-vassilis-pits).